# Determine "a" while knowing that this vector determines the same angle with these two vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors

[Click here to see the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCMrW.png)

We got this question on the test and I have no clue on how to solve it, can someone please point out how it is solved in a non- complex way?

Comment: Please take the time to enter key parts of your question as text instead of uploading a picture. Images are neither searchable not accessible to people using screen readers. If you don’t take any of your own time on posting the question, why do you expect anyone to spend their time to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two vectors $\mathbf{a,b,\ a.b=|a||b|}\cos\theta$ where $\theta $ is the angle from $\mathbf{a}$ to $\mathbf{b}$. Now by the given information $$\cos\theta=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+2}}$$ considering the dot product of first and second vectors and $$\cos\theta=\dfrac{2a+3}{3\sqrt{a^2+2}}$$ considering the dot product of first and third vectors. Use these two equations to find $a$.